# git submodule shows as changed in parent directory

Tags: git, git-submodules

I've got a library checked out as a *git submodule* in my project and I often make changes in the lib. Every time I commit that change the subsequent `git status` in the parent repo shows that the submodule has changed. I also use `__git_ps1` and so the parent dir prompt shows that there are uncommitted changes.

```
parent-project (master *) $ git diff
diff --git a/my-submodule b/my-submodule
index 5eb2e9f..fd40630 160000
--- a/my-submodule
+++ b/my-submodule
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Subproject commit 5eb2e9fdcb85ab5a1f57e622b17cc76e5af749b7
+Subproject commit fd406308851b5521980f4578960c428200c66371
```

I know of two options:

1. `git commit submodule` from the parent which creates unnecessary commits, or
2. remove and re-add the submodule which seems like an overkill.

Is there any way to tell the parent repo *Update the submodule ref to the latest master and move on*? I don't want to refer to a specific git revision, just to the head of *master* or whatever branch I choose.

Thanks!

Comment: *I often make changes in the lib* is the lib had to be tracked? if not, perhaps using gitignore can help.

Comment: @BagusTesa Hmm, that doesn't seem to help, just tried. First `git submodule add` complains that it's in `.gitignore`, but that can be forced. But even then the submodule commits still make the parent project dirty :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any way to tell the parent repo Update the submodule ref to the latest master

Yes, with the [`--remote` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt---remote):

```
git submodule update --remote
```

> and move on?

Well,... that would still change the submodule SHA1 tree, so you would still need to make a commit, but you can make said commit whenever you have made your own changes in the parent repository.

Maybe locally you could ignore that with:

```
cd /parent/repo
git update-index --assume-unchanged -- submoduleFolder # no trailing slash
```

Comment: *you would still need to make a commit* .. that's what I'd like to avoid. Instead of referring to a particular submodule commit id I'd like to refer to the submodule's master. Or ignore any changes in the submodule sha id (unfortunately `.gitignore` doesn't seem to help here).

Comment: @I-P-X See "True anture oof submodules": https://stackoverflow.com/a/1979194/6309. A submodule is *always* a SHA1 reference plus a remote URL. I have included in the answer a way to ignore it locally.

Comment: Thanks, `git update-index --assume-unchanged` seems to do the trick :)